# Slick proof that if an open set contains $\mathbb Q$ it has all irrational numbers, except a countable amount.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Basically I need help in proving that if $U\supseteq \mathbb Q $ is an open set in $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology then $\mathbb R \setminus U$ is countable.

I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Maybe we can use $U$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals?

Comment: Did the assignment say to prove that statement, or did it say "prove or disprove"?

Comment: What @bof said. It isn't true.

Comment: The assignment is non existent, I thought it was true.

Comment: Could you provide a counterexample?

Comment: If this were true, then $\mathbb{Q}$ would have full measure, but in fact it has measure zero.

Comment: You lost me there @ian

Comment: Take an enumeration $q_n$ of the rationals, take a positive number $\epsilon$, then $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (q_n-\epsilon 2^{-n},q_n+\epsilon 2^{-n})$ is an open set containing every rational. One way to prove that it does not contain every irrational is to note that it has measure $2 \epsilon$ while the whole line has infinite measure.

Comment: I need a set that is missing a number of irrational numbers that is not countable.

Comment: @dREaM What is wrong with taking $\mathbb R$ minus $\{i_1, \dots, i_n\}$ where $i_k$ are irrationals?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer that would give you a set that is missing a countable number of irrational numbers.

Comment: @dREaM Oh I see, the "not countable" referred to the missing numbers.

Comment: @dREaM How about $(1, 2)$? Presumably you don't just want *any* such set . . .

Comment: $(1,2)$ does not contain $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $E$ of real numbers whose decimal expansions have the form

$$.a_1\ 0\ a_2\ 0\ 0\ a_3\ 0\ 0\ 0\ a_4\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ \cdots ,$$

where each $a_n \in \{1,2\},$ is closed in $\mathbb {R},$ contains nothing but irrational numbers, and is uncountable (being in 1-1 correspondence with the set of binary sequences). Set $U=\mathbb {R}\setminus E$ for a counterexample.

Comment: How would one prove that set is closed?

Comment: @dREaM If it weren't closed, there would be a sequence of numbers in it with a limit outside of the set.

Comment: @dREaM Or provide a continuous bijection between this and the Cantor set, which we know is closed.

Comment: Thanks, the first argument worked.

Comment: @dREaM If a sequence in $E$ converges, it must eventually be constant in each decimal place.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Did you notice all the $0$'s I put in there?

Comment: No worries. I managed to find a proof I am comfortable with using the first suggestion @columbus8myhw gave

Comment: @columbus8myhw I'm not sure what we're disagreeing about. For $x\in E,$ let $d_n(x)$ be the number in the $n$th slot in the decimal expansion of  $x.$ Suppose $x_m$ is a sequence in $E$ that converges to some real number. Do you agree that for each fixed $n, d_n(x_m)$ is eventually constant as $m\to \infty?.$ That's all I'm saying, and it implies the limit of $x_m$ lies in $E.$

Comment: @zhw. Ohhhhhh. Sorry, I misunderstood — i'll delete my comments.

Comment: You don't have to delete them!

Comment: …too late?${{}{{}}}$

Comment: oh well ... I never delete my comments, even if they are uproariously off the mark (not saying yours were, maybe I didn't say it right to begin with). I think such discussions can be useful to some students. Anyway, nice conversing.

Answer (score 1):

Ian's comment provides an example of an open set containing the rationals which is *small*, in the sense that it can be written as the union of countably many open intervals the sum of whose lengths is $\le2\epsilon$ (for arbitrary fixed $\epsilon$). But, how do we know that such an interval isn't all (or most) of $\mathbb{R}$?

It seems intuitive, but then, it also probably seems intuitive that any open set containing $\mathbb{Q}$ consists of "most" of $\mathbb{R}$. So let's prove it.

Or, rather, let me outline how to prove it:

- I'll show $(*)$: that if $\{U_i: i\in I\}$ is any collection of open intervals which covers $[0, 1]$, then the sum of the lengths of the $U_i$s is at least 1. *(The length of an interval $(a, b)$ is just $b-a$.)*
- This is enough to prove the desired result: if we let $X$ be the set built as in Ian's comment with $\epsilon={1\over 4}$, say, then if $X$ were to be all-but-countably-much of $\mathbb{R}$, we could find a countable set $Y$ such that $[0, 1]\subseteq X\cup Y$ . . .
- . . . and it's easy to find a family of open intervals, the sum of whose lengths is $<{\epsilon\over 4}$ (say), which covers an open set (such as $Y$); so by covering $X$ and $Y$ sufficiently efficiently, we would contradict the first bullet point. Note that this is basically just Ian's comment! So this entire proof is basically a "dual" of the construction Ian already described.
- Now, the proof of $(*)$ splits into two cases. If $I$ is finite, then $(*)$ holds by induction on the size of $I$; exercise.
- However, what if $I$ is infinite? (That is, what if we're using infinitely many open intervals to cover $[0 1]$?) Then things get more complicated.
- Say $\alpha\in[0, 1]$ is *reachable* if there is some finite sequence of open intervals $U_{i_1}, . . . , U_{i_n}\in \{U_i: i\in I\}$ such that $0\in U_1$, $U_{i_k}\cap U_{i_{k+1}}\not=\emptyset$, and $\alpha\in U_{i_n}$. (So the $U_{i_k}$s “reach” from $0$ to $\alpha$.) Let $x$ be the least upper bound of the set of reachable $\alpha$ (the set of reachable $\alpha$ is bounded above by $1$, and nonempty since $0$ is reachable, so $x$ exists).
- EXERCISE: show that $x$ is reachable, and therefore that $x=1$.
- Since $1$ is reachable, there must be some *finite* subset of $\{U_i: i\in I\}$ which covers all of $[0, 1]$ already, so we are done (since finite covers use at least 1-much length).

This is (a special case of a broader theorem, the proof of which isn't much harder, though,) called the **Heine-Borel theorem**, and is basically the beginning of *measure theory*! The "minimum total length of a cover by open intervals" notion I've been kicking around is called *(outer) measure*. Measure theory is a really cool field, and it's full of weird counterintuitiveness!

Comment: This style of proving Heine-Borel is called *topological induction* or *real induction* - see e.g. http://math.uga.edu/~pete/realinduction.pdf.

Comment: Neither of those terms is standard or commonly used.  Which is not to say they are bad descriptions.

Comment: . . . Huh, you're right; I was absolutely convinced that they were standard, but googling around shows very little. That's weird.

Comment: Nice, Steve, but I think Zhw's answer beats you in terms of simplicity :-P

Comment: His answer contains 100% less measure theory, though.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was familiar with _continuous induction_ and _real induction_. I'm not sure where _topological induction_ would have come from, since it comes from ordered sets, not topologies. (Most topologies don't come from ordered sets. Right?)